# Netsuite (Inventory Details)

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I need to configure Inventory details using **Lot Numbered Assembly/Bill of Materials** details. and i tried the following code to achieve that.

```
        var recordScreate = nlapiCreateRecord('inventoryadjustment')
        recordScreate.setFieldValue('account', 850);
        recordScreate.setFieldValue('adjlocation', locationSvalue);
        recordScreate.setFieldValue('custbody_cseg1', jbSvalue);


       recordScreate.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventory', 'item', fgSvalue);
       recordScreate.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventory', 'location',locationSvalue);
       recordScreate.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventory', 'adjustqtyby',-hproductionSscrap);``



       var inventoryDetail = recordScreate.createCurrentLineItemSubrecord('inventory', 'inventorydetail');
       inventoryDetail.selectNewLineItem('inventoryassignment');
       inventoryDetail.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventoryassignment', 'issueinventorynumber',2793);
       inventoryDetail.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventoryassignment', 'quantity', -hproductionSscrap);
       inventoryDetail.commitLineItem('inventoryassignment');
       inventoryDetail.commit();

       recordScreate.commitLineItem('inventory');`
```

and i got the **Error_ "Invalid issueinventorynumber reference key 2793.0"**  can anyone please help in this to to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey Guys thanks for your support. Finally i got answer. Record was exist. What i did id...

i just passed that id into **String format not in Integer** like "2739" instead of 2739.. Corrected code is below...

```
var recordScreate = nlapiCreateRecord('inventoryadjustment')
    recordScreate.setFieldValue('account', 850);
    recordScreate.setFieldValue('adjlocation', locationSvalue);
    recordScreate.setFieldValue('custbody_cseg1', jbSvalue);


   recordScreate.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventory', 'item', fgSvalue);
   recordScreate.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventory', 'location',locationSvalue);
   recordScreate.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventory', 'adjustqtyby',-hproductionSscrap);``



   var inventoryDetail = recordScreate.createCurrentLineItemSubrecord('inventory', 'inventorydetail');
   inventoryDetail.selectNewLineItem('inventoryassignment');
   inventoryDetail.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventoryassignment', 'issueinventorynumber','2793');
   inventoryDetail.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventoryassignment', 'quantity', -hproductionSscrap);
   inventoryDetail.commitLineItem('inventoryassignment');
   inventoryDetail.commit();

   recordScreate.commitLineItem('inventory');
```

Comment: could you help me on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63343560/how-to-get-netsuite-bin-number-details-from-inventory-details-tab-using-soap-api

Answer (score 0):

"2739" is not a valid issueinventorynumber internal ID.  Double check the field you are writing to and verify that that value exists, and that you have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

Error_ "Invalid issueinventorynumber reference key 2793.0" Occurs because the id for lot number is not provided correctly....

For getting correct id of Lot number--> Go to you Lot Item record-> Then under Inventory Detail subtab click on the lot number which you want to select for inventory adjustment--> the new popup window will appear, at the end of the popup window's URL you will see the id which is something like   'id=**201**&l=T'  where 201 will be your ID.

Comment: could you help me on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63343560/how-to-get-netsuite-bin-number-details-from-inventory-details-tab-using-soap-api